# Set encoding in aptana 3

Tags: aptana3

I have just downloaded **Aptana 3.2.2** (standalone version) for the latest Mac OS X. I cannot find out how to **set the encoding** (preferable UTF-8) for my specific html-document. In Aptana 2 and in Visual Studio this is an easy catch, but I have now scanned all the menues in Aptana 3.2.2 without success.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that version for linux is similar as for Mac OS X, try right click on the specific file in the App Explorer and then go Properties (or try Alt + Enter while you edit file you want to change encoding). On the bottom of tab Resources you have "Text file encoding" where you can adjust this setting.
Also if you want to set encoding for whole project go Project -> Properties from the top menu which will let you change it for a bunch of files.